# Meteor's Load Order and Angular Modules

Tags: angularjs, meteor, directory-structure

The folder structure of my Angular-Meteor-app looks like this:

```
.
├── client
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── auth
│   │   │   ├── login
│   │   │   │   ├── login.controller.js
│   │   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   ├── register
│   │   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   ├── reset-password
│   │   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   ├── route.config.js
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   ├── app.module.js
│   │   │   ├── auth.module.js
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
├── ...
```

Please note that because of Meteor's load order I cannot put `auth.module.js` under the `auth` directory but have to place it under the `lib` directory. Otherwise Angular would complain that the *auth* module could not be injected when used in `login.controller.js`. (Files in subdirectories are loaded before files in parent directories, all files in `lib` are moved before everything else.)

What I would like is to move `auth.module.js` in the `auth` folder, so I have all files of my *auth* module in the right place:

```
.
├── client
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── auth
│   │   │   ├── login
│   │   │   │   ├── login.controller.js
│   │   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   ├── register
│   │   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   ├── reset-password
│   │   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   ├── auth.module.js
│   │   │   ├── route.config.js
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   ├── app.module.js
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
├── ...
```

Any idea how to manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got at least two options:

Make `client/auth` flat, so that the lexicographic ordering will load `auth.module.js` before `login.controller.js`.

```
│   │   ├── auth
│   │   │   ├── auth.module.js
│   │   │   ├── login.controller.js
│   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   ├── ...
```

Or use yet another `lib` sub-directory

```
│   │   ├── auth
│   │   │   ├── lib
|   │   │   │   ├── auth.module.js
│   │   │   ├── login
│   │   │   │   ├── login.controller.js
│   │   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   ├── ...
```

Of course, one could argue that your code should not depend in the load order, i.e., you should only use the auth code once everything is loaded, e.g., in `oMeteor.startup` or `onCreate` of templates.

Comment: I will use another `lib` sub-directory, like you've suggested... Thank you!